# error in building boost

Tags: c++, boost, build

I try to building boost1.62 from source(sorry for my english). My system is Linux(Debian wheezy)x86_64 with compiler gcc-6.3.
It's my configuration:

```
/home/user/boost/boost_1_62_0/bjam -j8 -d2  --layout=system --ignore-  site-config --user-config=/home/user/boost/boost_1_62_0/user-config.jam debug-symbols=on  --without-python
Performing configuration checks

- 32-bit                   : no
- 64-bit                   : yes
- arm                      : no
- mips1                    : no
- power                    : no
- sparc                    : no
- x86                      : yes

Building the Boost C++ Libraries.


- symlinks supported       : yes
- C++11 mutex              : yes
- lockfree boost::atomic_flag : yes
- Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_auto_declarations : yes
- Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_constexpr : yes
- Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_defaulted_functions : yes
- Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_final : yes
- Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_hdr_tuple : yes
- Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_lambdas : yes
- Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_noexcept : yes
- Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_nullptr : yes
- Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_rvalue_references : yes
- Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_template_aliases : yes
- Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_thread_local : yes
- Boost.Config Feature Check: cxx11_variadic_templates : yes
- has_icu builds           : yes
- zlib                     : yes
- bzip2                    : yes
- iconv (libc)             : yes
- icu                      : yes
- native-atomic-int32-supported : yes
- pthread-supports-robust-mutexes : yes
- compiler-supports-visibility : yes
- compiler-supports-ssse3  : yes
- compiler-supports-avx2   : yes
- gcc visibility           : yes
- long double support      : yes
- zlib                     : yes
- bzip2                    : yes

Component configuration:

- atomic                   : building
- chrono                   : building
- container                : building
- context                  : building
- coroutine                : building
- coroutine2               : building
- date_time                : building
- exception                : building
- fiber                    : building
- filesystem               : building
- graph                    : building
- graph_parallel           : building
- iostreams                : building
- locale                   : building
- log                      : building
- math                     : building
- metaparse                : building
- mpi                      : building
- program_options          : building
- python                   : not building
- random                   : building
- regex                    : building
- serialization            : building
- signals                  : building
- system                   : building
- test                     : building
- thread                   : building
- timer                    : building
- type_erasure             : building
- wave                     : building
```

I get the error in end without explanation:

```
common.copy stage/lib/libboost_wave.so.1.62.0

cp "bin.v2/libs/wave/build/gcc-6.3.0/release/debug-symbols-on/threading-multi/libboost_wave.so.1.62.0"  "stage/lib/libboost_wave.so.1.62.0"

ln-UNIX stage/lib/libboost_wave.so

ln -f -s 'libboost_wave.so.1.62.0' 'stage/lib/libboost_wave.so'

...failed updating 6 targets...
...skipped 8 targets...
...updated 1315 targets...
make[1]: *** [override_dh_auto_build] Ошибка 1
```

Help to understand what cause of error... What was wrong? I try to find errors in log and they are not there, just in end. Maybe trouble in boost.wave...

Comment: Can you try Boost 1.66?  This issue may already have been addressed.

Comment: I need just 1.62 for some soft

Comment: `boost1.62` : You can use the (10) patches from the Debian Stretch boost1.62 → `boost1.62_1.62.0+dfsg-4.debian.tar.xz` →   http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/b/boost1.62/boost1.62_1.62.0+dfsg-4.debian.tar.xz ... And the edited source code  http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/main/b/boost1.62/boost1.62_1.62.0+dfsg.orig.tar.bz2

Comment: @KnudLarsen, thank you very much